# How to create property from the path

Tags: swift, object

I need to manipulate properties of the dictionary from taking path to that property like 'a.b.c' and setting property value. I have root object 'obj' (NSObject derived) that has property named 'a' of the type of NSObject derived class. That class has property named 'b' that is dictionary `var map = [String: CGFloat]()` and 'c' is key name in the dictionary. If I call `obj.setValue(value, forKeyPath: 'a.b.c')` it works fine if property in dictionary exist. I would like to automatically create that property if it doesnt. Is there way?

Comment: What is the type of `obj`?

Comment: And how is the dictionary defined?

Comment: The Swift dictionary doesn't have the `setValue` method. Maybe you confused it with `NSDictionary`?

Answer (score 0):

`setValue(_:forKeyPath:)` is not a dictionary method, it is an `NSObject` method.

Implement `setValue(_:forUndefinedKey:)` and store the key-value pair yourself. Also need to implement `value(forUndefinedKey:)` for obtaining the value.

Comment: the dictionary is the object 'b' in the path of 'a.b.c'. Updated my question bit more

Comment: You cannot use dictionary like this. If you wish to use `setValue(_:forKeyPath:)`, you will have to have a wrapper object which will implement `setValue(_:forUndefinedKey:)` and `value(forUndefinedKey:)`. Perhaps you should not be using this API.